# Configuring Eclipse to compile Haskell with EclipseFP Plugin

Tags: eclipse, haskell

I just installed the EclipseFP plugin into my Eclipse setup (on Windows 7 32bit, if that matters), following the [instructions](http://eclipsefp.sourceforge.net/). Then I followed the directions in the Eclipse help docs to create a `Hello World` project successfully.

However, I'm fairly certain something is wrong, though I cannot figure out what. First of all, there's no syntax highlighting, even if I explicitly open files with the Haskell Editor. Secondly, hitting run launches the GHCi console in the Console tab. This is actually fairly useful, but does not sound right, since it doesn't *run* the file, only compile and load it. Additionally, the Outline view is empty, even when I open a moderately large Haskell file.

Last but not least, the project initially reported there was no Haskell implementation configured. I went into the preferences (though this is not described as being necessary anywhere) and manually added a GHC implementation, pointed to the bin directory of my Haskell Platform installation. As best I can tell, however, this has had no effect.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**EclipseFP appears to [no longer be actively maintained](http://jpmoresmau.blogspot.ca/2015/05/eclipsefp-end-of-life-from-me-at-least.html); use at your own risk.**

---

After a lot of great help from the developers of EclipseFP on their mailing list, I put together a set of instructions for installing the current (2.0.2) version of EclipseFP.  You can [read my email](https://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=AANLkTinoXBRrFMshHYiYSZucd%3Deb9TO8TrsehERxpzb0%40mail.gmail.com&forum_name=eclipsefp-develop) but below are the instructions - it's long, but not as hard as it looks, and the result is quite nice:

1. **[Install GHC/GHCi](http://hackage.haskell.org/platform/)** - but you've
   done that already, right?
2. **Install [Eclipse 3.5](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)+**
   If you haven't already got Eclipse (why not?!) download
   it - either the IDE for Java Developers if you're inclined to use it with Java as
   well, or just Eclipse Classic if not.  "Installation" consists simply of
   extracting the eclipse folder somewhere and launching the eclipse
   executable, there is nothing to actually install.  It prompts you to select
   a workspace, your user folder or your documents folder are good choices if
   you don't have a preference.
3. **Install [the EclipseFP plugin](http://eclipsefp.sourceforge.net/)**
   In Eclipse go to Help > Install New Software and paste
   `http://eclipsefp.sf.net/updates` into the Work with: field - hit enter.
   In the box below "Functional Programming" should show up after a few
   moments, cancel and retry it if it doesn't.  Expand "Functional Programming"
   and check the 2.x.x Haskell Support plugin.  Follow the rest of the steps,
   and EclipseFP will be installed, and will prompt you to restart Eclipse.
4. **Update Cabal**
   While you're waiting, launch a command prompt window (type cmd in the
   start bar on Win Vista/7) or terminal and enter 'cabal update'.  This will
   update the packages Haskell needs in order to let EclipseFP work.
5. **Configure EclipseFP**
   Go to Window > Preferences and expand the Haskell section.  Click on
   "Haskell Implementations" and click "Add".  Enter a reasonable name (I
   called it "Haskell Platform") and then browse to the bin directory of your
   GHC installation, which on Windows is something like "C:\Program
   Files\Haskell Platform\2010.2.0.0\bin".  It will populate the Version and
   Library folder items below, click Ok.  Click OK to save these preferences,
   then open the preferences window again.  Go to "Scion and Cabal" and click
   "Autodetect" on the right.  It should add an item to the list of Installed
   Cabal implementations, but if it does not, click add, give it a name like
   "Cabal" and give it the path to the Cabal executable, which on Windows is
   something like "C:\Program Files\Haskell
   Platform\2010.2.0.0\lib\extralibs\bin\cabal.exe".  Hit OK, and click Rebuild
   on the right to tell EclipseFP to build the "Scion server" which handles the
   syntax highlighting and file parsing.  Optionally under Editor check "Show
   line numbers" and uncheck "Show print margin", I think it makes the editor
   pane look better.  Then hit OK to exit preferences.
6. **Build the Scion Server**
   In theory, upon exiting the preferences window, EclipseFP will start
   doing a lot of work to build the Scion server.  If it does not, simply exit
   and restart Eclipse, and when it's restarted it will start building.  With
   any luck, this will run for a few minutes and then be done, however you may
   run into some trouble due to the finicky nature of Haskell's/Cabal's
   versioning system.  If it fails, try running "cabal update" again, or
   running something like "cabal install network-2.3" where network-2.3 is a
   package the build script reported wasn't right.  Once the Scion server is
   built, we're basically all set.  Restart Eclipse one more time for good
   measure.
7. **Create a Haskell Project**
   Switch to the Haskell perspective if this hasn't happened already - top
   right corner, click the Open Perspective icon, click Other if you don't see
   Haskell in the list, and select Haskell from the popup.  Now go to File >
   New > Haskel Project (or Project and then select Haskell Project) and create
   a project.  To create your first Haskell file, right click on the src
   flolder in the project and select New > Haskell Module.  This creates a
   Haskell file, you can do whatever you want with it.  To run the file, click
   the Run button (green circle, white triangle) near the top.  This will
   launch a basic GHCi terminal in the Console tab below with the prompt
   "Prelude>" if the file has errors, or "MODULENAME>" if it compiled
   successfully.  You can use this like the external GHCi terminal to run
   commands like :t, or to make function calls of the module.
8. **Configure How The File Runs**
   One last thing which will make your life easier is to tell EclipseFP to
   automatically reload the file when it's saved, and to run a function (for
   instance "main") after the file is reloaded.  To do this, click on the down
   arrow next to the run button, and select "Run Configurations".  Click on the
   configuration on the left of the file you want, then click on the Automation
   tab.  Check "Reload packages on save" if you don't want to have to type ":r"
   all day, and type a function name like "main" and check "Rerun command after
   reload" to run a command automatically.

Comment: @dimo - I just had "Could not locate the executable to launch" on run and I set the GHCI and I set the run configuration to "Haskell Application" and working directory as my project folder. It still does that on WIndows. On Ubuntu it did that at first and then I closed Eclipse and opened it and made a new project and it magically worked. But on Windows I am f*cked.

Comment: I'd guess you missed a step. Did you install Cabal and build the Scion server? If you followed all the steps here and it's not working, I'd suggest starting a new thread on the EclipseFP mailing list and linking to this post.

Comment: In step 4, you said "while you are waiting"; does it refer to step 3? i.e. does it mean step 4 can be carried out while step 3 is in progress?

Comment: @FleetCommand yes, cabal can be updated while EclipseFP is being installed - it's only needed once you try to run the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

[EclipseFP Plugin](http://eclipsefp.github.io/) [is not maintained since 2015-05-14](http://jpmoresmau.blogspot.ca/2015/05/eclipsefp-end-of-life-from-me-at-least.html) and does not seem to work with recent versions of Eclipse.

Comment: @David, if you look carefully you will see the other answer duplicated mine. The note at the top was added after I posted my answer. Without that note it was misleading and caused me to spend considerable time trying to get it to work before releasing it simply does not work anymore.

Comment: Oh, I didn't spot the edit. Sorry.